# How to populate a column in dataframe under given datetime value restiriction?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-datetime, fuzzy-comparison

Given the pandas dataframes `df1` and `df2`:

`df1`:

```
                           d  v
0 2018-02-16 13:39:55.562506  1
1 2018-02-16 10:18:56.768246  4
```

and `df2`:

```
                           d   vx
0 2018-02-16 13:39:56.668377  100
1 2018-02-16 14:01:05.766319  200
```

how can I extend `df1` with the `vx` values from `df2`, such that the timestamp are **almost** the same i.e. the values differ in no more than 2 seconds (and NaN where they do not match)?

Example:

```
                           d  v     vx
0 2018-02-16 10:18:56.768246  4    NaN
1 2018-02-16 13:39:55.562506  1  100.0
```

Below is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt

dt1 = dt.datetime(2018, 2, 16, 13, 39, 55, 562506)
dt2 = dt.datetime(2018, 2, 16, 10, 18 , 56, 768246)
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'v':[1,4], 'd':[dt1, dt2]})

dt3 = dt.datetime(2018, 2, 16, 13, 39 , 56, 668377)
dt4 = dt.datetime(2018, 2, 16, 14, 1 , 5, 766319)
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'vx':[100,200], 'd':[dt3, dt4]})
```

Comment: have you looked at merge or join?

Comment: What is the desired result if there are two or more timestamps in df1 which are within 2 seconds of the df2 timestamp?

Comment: @thesilkworm in case of one or more results, any value is accetpable

Comment: MaxU's answer below looks good then as it chooses the nearest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use [pd.merge_asof()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge_asof.html)

```
In [232]: pd.merge_asof(df1.sort_values('d'), df2, on='d', 
                        tolerance=pd.to_timedelta('2S'), 
                        direction='nearest')
Out[232]:
                           d  v     vx
0 2018-02-16 10:18:56.768246  4    NaN
1 2018-02-16 13:39:55.562506  1  100.0
```

NOTE: the joining field (`d` in your case) must be sorted for both DFs